# Convert Byte type into float

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have a `numpy` array:

```
import numpy as np
Boolval = np.array([b'false',b'true',b'false',b'false',b'false',b'false',b'false',b'false'])
```

I am trying to convert each value into the entire array with value 0 or 1 (e.g. `[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`).

I tried the following:

```
import struct
print(struct.unpack('f',Boolval))
```

It throws an error: `struct.error: unpack requires a buffer of 4 bytes`

I tried with just one value,

```
print(struct.unpack("f", Boolval[1]))
```

It gives the value of `(7.24431922380234e+22,)`. Not 1 or 0.

Comment: How did you even get an array like that? The solution is likely to change something about the code that got you to this point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are not byte values, they are binary strings. Try something like

```
>>> [int(b == b'true') for b in Boolval]
[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

This will check if the item is equal to `b'true'` and convert the truth value (`True` or `False`) to an `int`.

Comment: it did not work. the error : ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: b'true'

Comment: I am almost certain that you copied the code in my answer incorrectly.

Answer (score 2):

```
In [253]: Boolval = np.where([0,1,0,0,1,0,1],b'true',b'false')                                         
In [254]: Boolval                             # the repr display                                                         
Out[254]: 
array([b'false', b'true', b'false', b'false', b'true', b'false', b'true'],
      dtype='|S5')
In [255]: print(Boolval)                 # the str display                                                              
[b'false' b'true' b'false' b'false' b'true' b'false' b'true']

In [256]: Boolval!=b'false'                                                                            
Out[256]: array([False,  True, False, False,  True, False,  True])
In [257]: Boolval==b'true'                                                                             
Out[257]: array([False,  True, False, False,  True, False,  True])
```

We can convert it to boolean array with a comparison to a bytestring:

```
In [256]: Boolval!=b'false'                                                                            
Out[256]: array([False,  True, False, False,  True, False,  True])
In [257]: Boolval==b'true'                                                                             
Out[257]: array([False,  True, False, False,  True, False,  True])
```

and to an integer array with a `astype` conversion:

```
In [258]: (Boolval!=b'false').astype(int)                                                              
Out[258]: array([0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1])

In [259]: np.where(Boolval==b'true')                                                                   
Out[259]: (array([1, 4, 6]),)
```

And the list comprehension approach:

```
In [260]: [int(b == b'true') for b in Boolval]                                                         
Out[260]: [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1]
```

If we start with a list, the list comprehension is often faster.  But starting with an array it is likely to be slower.  Though here the sample is small, and the string equality test isn't nearly as fast as numeric operations.